# JQuery show/hide or Toggle with an image + / -

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, show

Hi alle i have the fallowing code for the show and hide.
But in my browsers theres nu plus or minus image.

```
$(window).ready(function() {
      $('header').click(function() {
        var text = $(this).children(' #bericht');

        if (text.is(':hidden')) {
            text.slideDown('200');
            $('img', this).attr('src', 'images/icons/up.png').show(200);        
        } else {
            text.slideUp('200');
            $('img', this).attr('src', 'images/icons/down.png').show(200);      
        }

    });

    $('img', this).attr('src', 'images/icons/up.png').show(200);

  });
});
```

This is my html code what i have.

```
<section id="box-ui">
    <header class="head-title">Test kopje<img class="toggle"  src="images/icons/up.png" /></header>
    <div id="bericht" class="berichtui">
    <a href="#">Beetje tekst hier maar....?</a><br>
    Beetje tekst hier maar....?<br>
    Beetje tekst hier maar....?<br>
    Beetje tekst hier maar....?<br>
    Beetje tekst hier maar....?</div>
</section>

<section id="box-ui">
    <header class="head-title">Test kopje<img class="toggle"  src="images/icons/up.png" /></header>
    <div class="berichtui">
    Beetje tekst hier maar....?<br>
    Beetje tekst hier maar....?<br>
    Beetje tekst hier maar....?<br>
    Beetje tekst hier maar....?<br>
    Beetje tekst hier maar....?</div>
</section>
```

So what am i doing wrong people who can tell me ;)

This is what i have on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ffLVg/2/).

Comment: Change `$(this).children(' #bericht')` to `$(this).closest('section').find('.berichtui')`. Also, you might want to get rid of all those duplicate IDs, that's invalid HTML and will cause you problems if you try to select by ID. If it's used more than once, make it a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the current document has a ready event, the window does not.
In the last line of code where you're setting the source, `this` is the window object ?
The ID `box-ui` is used twice, and so are some of the other ID's ?
Don't quote the speed for animation methods.
You have also set the arrow image as the background.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('header').on('click', function () {
        var section = $(this).closest('section'),
            text    = section.find('.berichtui'), // use classes, not ID
            img     = $(this).find('img'),
            state   = text.is(':hidden');

        text[state?'slideDown':'slideUp'](200);
        img.prop('src', function() {
            return state ? 'images/icons/up.png' : 'images/icons/down.png';
        });
    });

    $('.box-ui img').show(200);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ffLVg/14/)

Comment: +1 because technically you answered first, i posted first but deleted as it was not complete and then re-posted. I have mentioned OP as well.